# How to pass custom props into QueryRenderer render function?

Tags: reactjs, relayjs, relay, relaymodern

Given the following QueryRenderer component:

```
class ProjectQueryRenderer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.renderProjectList = this.renderProjectList.bind(this);
  }

  renderProjectList({ error, props }) {
    if (props) {
      return (
        <ProjectList
          connection={props.viewer.allProjects}
          onSelectProject={this.props.onSelectProject}
          selectedProject={this.props.selectedProject}
        />
      );
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <QueryRenderer
        environment={environment}
        query={ProjectsQuery}
        render={this.renderProjectList}
      />
    );
  }
}

ProjectQueryRenderer.propTypes = {
  onSelectProject: Proptypes.func.isRequired,
  selectedProject: Proptypes.string.isRequired,
};
```

The problem I have is that `renderProjectList` is not executed again when my own `selectedProject` prop changes value. The `render` method obviously does get triggered, but since neither any of the props of `QueryRenderer` is changed, `renderProjectList` is not invoked either.

What is the best approach to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing a render function into `QueryRenderer`, you can pass in the whole ProjectList component as a property along with any props that component needs to render from the parent. They extra props show up in `QueryRenderer` as `other`. See below:

```
class ProjectQueryRenderer extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <QueryRenderer
        environment={environment}
        query={ProjectsQuery}
        component={ProjectList}
        onSelectProject={this.props.onSelectedProject}
        selectProject={this.props.selectedProject}
      />
    );
  }
}

ProjectQueryRenderer.propTypes = {
  onSelectProject: Proptypes.func.isRequired,
  selectedProject: Proptypes.string.isRequired,
};
```

and now QueryRenderer

```
class QueryRenderer extends Component {

  render() {
    const {environment, query, component, ...other} = this.props 

    // parameters to component that QueryRenderer computes
    // based on environment, query, etc...
    // plus also pass in all the extra props that are coming from
    // ProjectQueryRenderer (like onSelectProject)
    const computedProp = //something

    return (
     <div>
       <component computedProp={computedProp} {...other} />
     </div>
   )
  }
}
```

This way, both ProjectQueryRenderer and QueryRenderer can pass props into a arbitrary component into QueryRenderer and you can reuse QueryRenderer will other types of components as well.

Comment: Not sure I understand this correctly. The example above gives an `Uncaught TypeError: this.props.render is not a function` error.

Comment: I changed the `render` prop name to `component` but it's up to you to find an appropriate name for it. Maybe my solution is not entirely what you are looking for. I am looking at it again and I am working. Does `ProjectList` depend on properties that are past to it both from `ProjectQueryRenderer` and also `QueryRenderer`? If so there is another solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that successfully rerenders my list component (without performing an api request) each time one of my injected props changes. I had to define my component in the `render` function so that I could access the new prop values.

Below the result as a functional component:

```
const ProjectQueryRenderer = ({ onSelectProject, selectedProject }) => {
  const comp = ({ error, props }) => {
    if (props) {
      return (
        <ProjectList
          connection={props.viewer.allProjects}
          onSelectProject={onSelectProject}
          selectedProject={selectedProject}
        />
      );
    }
  };
  return (
    <QueryRenderer
      environment={environment}
      query={ProjectsQuery}
      render={comp}
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: The downside to this approach is that you create a new definition for the `comp` function every time `ProjectQueryRenderer` needs to render.